# 'str' object is not callable Python to SQL database

Tags: python

I'm trying to enter details into an SQL database through Python.  I have already created the database with fields customerID, firstname, surname, town and telephone.

When running this function, I get the error 'str' object is not callablefor the line where I am trying to INSERT the values of the variables.

```
import sqlite3
#function used to add a new customer, once confirmed save the customer in a 
#customer list
def add_customer():

    #open up the clients database
    new_db = sqlite3.connect('clients.db')

    #create a new cursor object to be able to use the database
    c = clients_db.cursor()
    print("Add customer")
    firstname = ""
    while len(firstname) == 0:
        firstname = input("Enter the customer's first name: ")
    surname = ""
    while len(surname) == 0:
        surname = input("Enter the customer's surname:  ")
    town = ""
    while len(town) == 0:
        town=input("Enter the customer's town: ")
    telephone = '1'
    while len(telephone) != 11:
        while telephone[0] != '0':
            telephone = input("Please enter the customer's telephone number: ")
            if telephone[0] != '0':
                print ("telephone numbers must begin with zero")
            elif len(telephone) != 11:
                print("must have 11 numbers")

    #check that data has been entered
    print(firstname,surname,town,telephone)



    #insert data into the customer table
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?,?,)'(firstname, surname, town, telephone))

    print("Customer added successfully ...")

    clients_db.commit()
    clients_db.close()

    if choice ==1:
        another = input("Would you like to add another? yes [y]  or no [n] --> ")
        if another=='y':
            add_customer()
        else:
            main_menu()
```

Comment: Please include the **full traceback** when asking for help with errors, lest you leave us guessing where it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a comma between the SQL statement string and the parameters:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?,?,)'(firstname, surname, town, telephone))
#                                                       ^
```

so you effectively do this: `"some string"(arg1, arg2, ...)`, trying to treat the string as a function.

Simply insert a comma there:

```
c.execute(
    'INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?,?,)',
    (firstname, surname, town, telephone))
```